# Python Error when setting self.var in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, syntax-error

I'm programming a python game, and my `Hero` class starts like this:

```py
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.class = ""
        while self.class not in ["mage", "fighter"]:
            print("What class are you?")
            self.class = input("Mage or Fighter: ").lower()
        self.name = name.title()
        self.level = 1
        self.enimieskilled = 0
        self.hp = self.level * 5
        self.attacks = spells[self.class]
```

I later create a hero with:
`player = Hero(input("What is your name? "))`

But when I run this program, I get:

```
File "app.py", line 26
    self.class = ""
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried commenting out all the `self.class`'s, as so:

```py
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, name):
        #self.class = ""
        #while self.class not in ["mage", "fighter"]:
        #    print("What class are you?")
        #    self.class = input("Mage or Fighter: ").lower()
        self.name = name.title()
        self.level = 1
        self.enimieskilled = 0
        self.hp = self.level * 5
        #self.attacks = spells[self.class]
```

and it runs! I have checked and all of my paranthesies are ok.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: class is a reserved python keyword, that's why it's not working :) try with `self.class_name` or something else

Comment: Don't do IO inside `Hero.__init__`; both the name and the class should be passed as arguments instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is a reserved python keyword, that's why it's not working :) try with `self.class_name` or something else

Answer (score 1):

The word `class` is a reserved one, it belongs to the language, you can only use it for declaring classes.